# php arrays multidimension

Tags: php, arrays

i just cooked up a scraping script and it works. Now i get this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => example stuff
            [1] => example stuff
            [2] => example stuff
            [3] => example stuff
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => /spellen/thumbs/a/aladdinwildride_6524.jpg
        [1] => /spellen/thumbs/t/toystory3_3476.jpg
        [2] => /spellen/thumbs/f/fred-flintstone-bobsled_2180.jpg
        [3] => /spellen/thumbs/m/madagascar-2.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => spel Alladin Wide Rit
        [1] => spel Toy Story 3
        [2] => spel Bedrock Bobsledding blowout
        [3] => spel Madagascar 2 Ontsnap naar Afrika

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => /spellen/cartoons/2096/alladin-wide-rit.html
        [1] => /spellen/cartoons/1989/toy-story-3.html
        [2] => /spellen/cartoons/1362/bedrock-bobsledding-blowout.html
        [3] => /spellen/cartoons/237/madagascar-2-ontsnap-naar-afrika.html

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => l
        [1] => l
        [2] => l
        [3] => l

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Speel Alladin Wide Rit online
        [1] => Speel Toy Story 3 online
        [2] => Speel Bedrock Bobsledding blowout online
        [3] => Speel Madagascar 2 Ontsnap naar Afrika online

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
        [1] => e
        [2] => e
        [3] => e

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => /images/thumb_frame_top.gif
        [1] => /images/thumb_frame_top.gif
        [2] => /images/thumb_frame_top.gif
        [3] => /images/thumb_frame_top.gif

    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => f
        [1] => f
        [2] => f
        [3] => f

    )
```

)

Now I would like a simple `foreach` that return me each `$matches[1][0]`, `$matches[2][0]` and `$matches[3][0]`.

I've been trying to get this for hours but no luck. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `foreach($matches as $array) { echo $array[0]; }` should do the trick. Hard to tell exactly what you need. Try it, see if we're close.

Comment: @Tornado Please do not add compliments as an edit.

Comment: You "cooked up" a scraping script, but you don't know how to iterate over an array?? Are you sure you didn't "copy and paste" a scraping script?

Comment: yes, its amazing what you can with hours of time and google. now i see a page with lots of info but only need 3 elements of every array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $result[] = array(
        $match[1],
        $match[2],
        $match[3],
    );
    // or unset($match[0]); if you don't need the original array anymore
    // or array_splice($match, 0, 1); if you also want to rearrange the keys
}
```

Comment: hi, well i dont need $matches[1][0] $matches[2][0] and $matches[3][0] in a simple array. the rest i dont need

Comment: @StefandeWal Did you want this?

Comment: jack, thanks for the answer. that is the answer i need. thanks again :P

Comment: @StefandeWal Your'e welcome. Just a tip: when you find an answer that you consider is the one that fits your needs better you must *accept* it by clicking the tick mark on the left side. That's how StackOverflow works :)

Comment: aha got it...thanks jack

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($matches as $match){

    // $match[0] is what you need

}
```

If you want results wrapped in a new array, you can reduce original array as:

```
$newArray = array_reduce($matches, function(&$result, $match){

  $result[] = $match[0];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is this what you want?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++)
{
    print $matches[$i][0];
}
```

Comment: i'll try and explain.

i would like a new array which only has in it:
matches[1][0]
$matches[2][0]
and
$matches[3][0]

Comment: Do you always and only need these 3 variables? if yes, why dont you just access them manually and push them in an array?

Comment: that is what i would want yes. but i cant get the php code for it right :P

Comment: oh well oh well.. you really need to know and WRITE what you actually want.. hard to answer for you

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($matches as $j => $match) {
   foreach ($match as $i => $mi) {
       if ($i != 0) unset($matches[$j][$i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the first three:

```
$newArray = array(
    $matches[1][0],
    $matches[2][0],
    $matches[3][0]
);
```

Result:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => /spellen/thumbs/a/aladdinwildride_6524.jpg
        [1] => spel Alladin Wide Rit
        [2] => /spellen/cartoons/2096/alladin-wide-rit.html
    )
```

Comment: that is almost right. that is only one of the 42 present in the original array. how can get the rest?

Comment: What do you mean the rest, you said you only wanted the first 3? Do you want the `0` element for each parent element?

Comment: this is what i would like in an array:
$matches[1][0]
$matches[2][0]
$matches[3][0]


$matches[1][1]
$matches[2][1]
$matches[3][1]


$matches[1][2]
$matches[2][2]
$matches[3][2]

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your pattern, are you trying get elements that match a keyword?